# How to check if specific user is allowed to download specific content?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a download center in my website where specific users can download specific content for which they have paid for. I thinking of creating a MySQL table like :

```
items | user1 | user2 |user3 
----------
item1 | true  |false  |false
----------
item2 | false | true  |false
----------
```

and then checking if user is allowed. In this case I have to add a new column for every new user and this could be a problem with increasing no. of users.

I doubt if this is a good or efficient way.

Please suggest if there is any better approach.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem: http://www.amazon.ca/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Relational/dp/0201752840 or many others can help you in this.

Comment: Better if you have an items table and a permissions table that links item ids  to users. Items (itemID,itemName) and permissions (itemID,userID,hasPermission). You should definitely look around on google for help with database design

Comment: remove the 'add a column' as an option

Comment: @ Terminus  I got it.  Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are right. Having such intended increasing number of columns is a sign of poor relational design. This design is called "One Big Spreadsheet", that is generated when you want to treat relational database as an MS-Excel file.

The solution for that is to create 3 tables (below demonstration is the minimum columns you will need):

1. `users` table with columns: `id`, `username`
2. `files` table with columns: `id`, `code`
3. `users_files` table that connects the other two, with columns: `id`, `user_id` (FK), `table_id` (FK)

Where (FK) stands for *Foreign Key* This is a many to many relation.